serial communication php to arduino mega
i want to turn on led pin on arduino mega using php code. i'm using phpserial in order to communicate with the arduino board, but instead of turning on the new led, it turns on the last led.
below is my code, based on this thread
anyone have any clue how can i make it work correctly?
BTW, the arduino part of the code works when i upload it to arduino IDE.
    <?php
    include 'PhpSerial.php';
    class ArduinoCommunication
    {
        private $serial;

        public function __construct($port, $baudRate)
        {
            $this->serial = new PhpSerial();
            $this->serial->deviceSet($port);
            $this->serial->confBaudRate($baudRate);
            $this->serial->confParity("none");
            $this->serial->confCharacterLength(8);
            $this->serial->confStopBits(1);
            $this->serial->deviceOpen("w");
            $this->serial->deviceOpen();
        }

        public function turnOnLED()
        {
            $this->sendCommand(1);
        }
    
        public function turnOffLED()
        {
            $this->sendCommand('0');
        }

        private function sendCommand($command)
        {
            $this->serial->sendMessage($command);
        }
    
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            $this->serial->deviceClose();
        }
    }

    $arduinoPort = 'COM3';
    $baudRate = 9600;

    $arduino = new ArduinoCommunication($arduinoPort, $baudRate);

    $arduino->turnOnLED();
    sleep(2); // Wait for 2 seconds

    $arduino->closeConnection();
    ?>

    byte led = A5;

    void setup() {
        pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
        Serial.begin(9600);     

        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(led,LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }

    void loop() {
    }


What do you means "new led" and "last led", your Arduino only has only one led defined and connected to pin A5. There is also no communication code in your Arduino code that listening to what sent by PHP code.

right, my arduino has only one led connected to pin A5, but i have more led pins on the board. and when i execute this code it turn on the last led that was on, instead of A5.

i also tried to add the below code to the arduino part, but it doesn't work code
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // Read command until newline character
command.trim(); // Remove any leading/trailing whitespace
